# SAS to Google Bigquery using Simba ODBC Driver

Tags: sas, odbc, simba

Not able to connect from SAS to Google Bigquery using Simba ODBC Driver.
OS:Linux

ODBC.ini

```
   [GoogleBQ]    
   Driver=<path for googlebigqueryodbc_sb64.so file path> 
   Description=Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery (64-bit) DSN
   Catalog=npower-qa
   OAuthMechanism=0
   Email=<service -accoun@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
   LogonID=
   Password=
   TrustedCerts=<Path for cacerts.pem>
   RefreshToken= < Token >
   SQLDialect=1
   KeyFilePath=<file path for .p12 file >
   AllowLargeResults=0
   ProxyHost=<proxy ip>
   ProxyPort=<proxy port>
```

Linux Command to test ODBC connectivity:

```
$ isql -v GoogleBQ
```

Error:

> [S1000][unixODBC][Simba][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'NoSQLGetPrivateProfileString' and component ID 1:
>   Could not open error message files - Check that "/shared/SAS/simba/googlebigqueryodbc/lib/64/$(INSTALLDIR)/ErrorMessages/en-US/ODBCMessages.xml" or "/shared/SAS/simba/googlebigqueryodbc/lib/64/$(INSTALLDIR)/ErrorMessages/ODBCMessages_en-US.xml" exists and are accessible.

Comment: Please format your error message